# Using Powershell to Delete files based on folder names, dates (years and months) and timestamps

Tags: powershell

I have just taken over a server, which contains a folder to store database backups

D:\Backups

In here, there are folders named 2019, 2020, 2021. In these folders are folders for months, named January, February, March etc and in these are folders for days 01, 02 to 31.

In each folder for a day, there are 3 database backups dbname_timestamp.bak

Ideally, what I want to achieve going forward is that for anything 2021 or later (2022, 2023 etc), we find the folder for the previous month (so today, we would navigate to D:\Backups\2021\August) and delete all folders except 01 and 15.

Then in folders 01 and 15 we would only keep the earliest file in that folder. So we would remove 2 bak files from each of these folders.

Prior to 2021, there was not an organised solution to keep backups, so anything before 2021 is a little bit confused and would not work with this solution. We need to keep all the data currently in the 2019 and 2020 folders.

My question is (please), is there a way in which Powershell would be able to compute that it needs to be looking in the 2021 folder (current year) and then in the August folder (previous month).

I'm new to powershell and this is currently proving a little difficult to perfect.
I'm more than happy to write the code myself (I'm not asking for a free script), I just need help knowing the best way to translate the current date/time on the O/S to put in this Powershell code.

Any thoughts or tips would be greatly appreciated. Stevie

Comment: It's trivial to get the metadata of a file with PowerShell.  You can loop through each folder and each file in each folder and look at the file's metadata (creation date, modification date, etc.) to determine what should be done with the file. It would be best if you considered moving the file until you are comfortable with the script output.

Comment: purely as an aside ... **_please avoid using month or day names for dates in file/folder names._** it will save you lots of future troubles by sticking with the month or day number ... since that sorts naturally into chronological order. plus, try to use `yyyy-MM-dd` since that also is a format that sorts into a natural chronological order.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the month's full name using `Get-Date` like below. This script should work for the folder structure you described, but make sure all the paths are correct:

```
# Assumes folder structure is (for example): D:\Backups\2021\September\27\file.txt

# Find the folder for the previous month (MMMM denotes long month name):
$year = (Get-Date).AddMonths(-1).Year
$MonthName = (Get-Date).AddMonths(-1) | Get-Date -Format 'MMMM'

# Get a list of all the daily folders for last month
$Dailies = Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path "D:\Backups\$Year\$MonthName"

# Delete all but two of the daily folders:
Foreach ($day in $Dailies) {
  # Keep backups from the 1st and 15th
  If ($day.name -notin '01','15') {
    Remove-Item $day.FullName -Recurse -WhatIf
  }
  # In 1st and 15th folders, only keep oldest file
  Else {
    Get-ChildItem $day.FullName | 
        Sort CreationTime | 
        Select -Skip 1 | 
        Remove-Item -WhatIf
  }
}
```

I also added `-WhatIf` so you can safely try it out without deleting anything.

---

`Get-Date` uses the current Culture settings to get the month name, so if you have remote connections or use a different language than your backup program, you may want to specify a culture to use instead:

```js
$MonthName = [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName((Get-Date).AddMonths(-1).Month)
```

Comment: *Perhaps* to simply slightly, `$lastMonthYear = (Get-Date).AddMonths(-1) | Get-Date -Format 'yyyy\\MMMM'`